# How can I prevent an Ubuntu 16.04 user from exiting rbash?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

On `Ubuntu 16.04`, I would like to restrict specific user's access to `rbash`. I had set the user's login shell into `rbash` using the command:

```
usermod -s /bin/rbash localuser
```

When I `ssh` into the box as this user and enter:

```
/bin/bash
```

the user is able to exit the `rbash` shell and use `bash`.

How can I restrict this user's access to `rbash`, and prevent him from switching to `bash`?

Comment: welcome to U&L, that looks strange, using rbash (in ubuntu 18.X) won't allow me to call `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks, if i login to the device directly as the user, i can not change to bash as i receive ' /bin/bash restricted cannot specify '/' in command' ,  however when i SSH into the box from another host i can use /bin/bash to exit rbash

Answer (score -1):

If you like to use this feature, you should set up special code in the file `/etc/profile` that is only executed by the shells that have a last path component (see `$0`) that starts with an `r` and set up a special `PATH` for the restricted shells.

Set up e.g. a directory `/usr/rbin`, make this the only `PATH` element and install links to the commands that the restricted user shoule be allowed to call. Be very careful with this selection and avoid commands that allow a shell escape. Note that `ed` called as `red` is a safe editor.

Note that after `/etc/profile` has been executed, `PATH` cannot be modified anymore.
If you do not do that, the `rbash` user has the usual `PATH` and thus is allowed to call `bash` to get the default verson of `bash`.

You should make some experiments in order to be sure that you did everything correctly. Unfortunately, the `bash` man page is not really helpful, so let me point to the restricted man page for the `Bourne Shell` for more informaton: 
http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1m/rsh.1m.html

This mentions that `$HOME/.profile` is permitted to make changes to `PATH`, so if this also applies to `rbash`, you would need to make `$HOME/.profile` unmodifyable for the user. You could do this by making this file `immutable` via the BSD file flags.

Comment: This setup will not prevent a user from opening an unrestricted shell using `ssh user@host -t bash`. See https://serverfault.com/questions/1093243/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-rbash-when-logging-in-via-ssh/1093244